# Getting the lowest value with a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, minimum

Can this Query also be written with a subquery?

What I have:

```
SELECT name, lifeExpectancy from country
WHERE lifeExpectancy IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY lifeExpectancy ASC
LIMIT 1
```

What the result should be:

```
name     | lifeExpectancy
-------------------------
Zambia   |           37.2
```

Comment: Is this an assignment or test question? It could be written with a joined subquery and a `MIN()` aggregate, but the query you have ordering `lifeExpectancy` with a `LIMIT` is probably faster.

Comment: When bringing an assignment, exam, or interview question here, please be transparent about it in your question. Many of us are happy to assist you if you are stuck, given solid evidence of an attempt at solving it, but the community does not like being treated as an answer service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
SELECT name, lifeExpectancy from country
WHERE lifeExpectancy = (SELECT MIN(lifeExpectancy) FROM country)
LIMIT 1
```

You still need `LIMIT 1` in case there are multiple countries the share the maximum lifeExpectancy. If lifeExpectancy is known to be unique, at least for the maximum, or you are OK with returning multiple rows when there's a tie for first place, you can omit the `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT name, lifeExpectancy from country
WHERE lifeExpectancy = (SELECT MIN(lifeExpectancy) FROM country)
```

Comment: here is gets so strange, this gives me: Andorra - 83.5

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT name, MIN(lifeExpectancy) AS lifeExpectancy from country;
```

Comment: The age is correct but the country isn't. This gives me Aruba - 37.2